# prevent `sizeof` operator being called for a complete type in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14

In C++, you can prevent a function from being used on `T` using the `= delete` syntax. You can't call `sizeof` using an incomplete type.

However, I was wondering, is there a way to prevent `sizeof` from being used on a complete type?

My initial attempts went something like this:

```
size_t operator sizeof(T) = delete;
```

Which obviously didn't work.

Now, from research online, I wasn't able to find anything suggesting that it was possible to prevent `sizeof` from being used on a type, unless that type was incomplete.

So, is there any way to prevent the `sizeof` operator from being used with a class (either using the `= delete` syntax or otherwise), that results in a compile-time error?

Anything is appreciated, no matter how hacky, and a solution that works *most* of the time is fine, too. C++14 compatible and no external libraries, though.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/353058).

Comment: Seems like you need a formal code review process and an explicit rule against using `sizeof` if it's such an issue.

Comment: @JohnFilleau it came up at work as a suggestion to another problem. As is probably obvious, this was not the way to go, but I was curious about if it's even possible.

Comment: Can you tell us what the other problem was? Giving an XY problem and witholding the X is maddening.

Comment: With a complete type?  No.  But if you only use incomplete types (which are opaque types), and free standing functions passing pointer or references to the incomplete type as an argument, then only on the implementation side of the type could a `sizeof` be done.

Comment: @JohnFilleau We essentially wanted an opaque type but with the ability to use method call syntax on it.

So in C you might do:

    `// .h`

    `struct T;`

    `void f(T);`

We wanted to be able to have `f` as a member function and write `t->f()`.

Comment: Which involves basically removing anything that an opaque type wouldn't have, including `sizeof`

Comment: Someone mentioned pimpl as a solution but we really needed something zero-cost in this specific case.

Comment: But isn't pimpl exactly equivalent to an opaque pointer + non-member functions?

Comment: You can't have `f` as a member function of an incomplete or opaque type.  You could get close by either using an interface to the real type (a façade pattern, and factory function), or wrapping a user-facing class around a private implementation (a pointer to implementation pattern).  But if you also must have zero overhead, and presumably means you can't even have a virtual function table, then you'll have to resort to free-standing functions.  Because C++ *uniform function call syntax* failed to be approved.

Comment: You have two types, one has size of 42 and the other has no discoverable size, and they are identical in every other respect. What are the specific practical advantages of the second type over the first one in your application?

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely. sizeof is not a function, it's a builtin operator. As it's necessary under the hood for the correct behavior of new (memory size to allocate for some object), I can't see how you could remove it.

But if the goal is to hide implementation size you could add some indirection layer and hide the actual type behind some facade of fixed size, but it wouldn't be a zero cost abstraction.

Comment: Specifically, this is where [the pImpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) can be helpful.